# Displaying images in tableview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image, tableview

I didnt get any images displayed, only the filename is shown.

Currently im using this codes:

```
NSString *filePath = [[self documentsPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@""];

NSFileManager *imagesFileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];


imagesArr = [[imagesFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:filePath error:nil]filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.jpg'"]];


arryList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[imagesArr copy]];//display text
imagesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];//display image

for (NSString *anImage in arryList) {
    anImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/%@",anImage];
    [imagesList addObject:anImage];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `for` loop , you are just adding the file path to the array instead of UIImage.

Change the for loop as follows:

```
NSString *docPath = [self documentsPath];

for (NSString *anImagePath in arryList) {
    anImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",docPath,anImagePath];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:anImagePath];
    if ( image )
      [imagesList addObject:image];
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it didnt work, the app crash.                            *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil object at 0'

Comment: Actually the image path was wrong. Then only I noticed. I have updated my answer. Check that.

Comment: the app crash '-[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x574f000', i tried to solve the problem and even post another question but can't

Comment: Put the whole crash log. Without that no one can solve your problem.

Comment: 2011-11-30 13:05:08.895 Care3[530:207] -[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6167a10
2011-11-30 13:05:08.896 Care3[530:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6167a10'

Comment: We are nowhere call `length` with UIImage object. It seems the app crashes somewhere else except from this code. Enable [NSZombie](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/debugging/tracking-down-exc_bad_access-errors-with-nszombieenabled.html) to find the exact place where the app crashes.

Comment: @user1063318 and @Aadhira the reason this code doesn't work is that `forin` doesn't want you to modify an item in a collection while cycling through that collection.  I've posted another answer to your question, @user1063318.